# trying to make a csv file from scrape data from Python

Tags: python, export, export-to-csv

I'm new to Python and any type of coding ...I hope this is not too easy question.

I'm trying to make a csv file from the scrape data from the web.

AttributeError: 'Doctype' object has no attribute 'find_all'

But this error wont go away!

here's the whole code

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request


req = urllib.request.Request('http://www.mobygames.com/game/tom-clancys-rainbow-six-siege',headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,'lxml')

scores = soup.find_all("div")

filename = "scores1.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")

headers = "Hi, Med, Low\n"

f.write(headers)

for scores in soup:
    scoreHi = scores.find_all("div", {"class":"scoreHi"})
    Hi = scoreHi[0].text
    scoreMed = scores.find_all("div", {"class":"scoreMed"})
    Med = scoreMed[0].text
    scoreLow = scores.find_all("div", {"class":"scoreLow"})
    Low = scoreLow[0].text

    print ("Hi: " + Hi)

    print ("Med: " + Med)

    print ("Low: "+ Low)

    f.write(Hi + "," + Med.replace(",","|") + "," + Low + "\n")


f.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first assign to scores:

```
scores = soup.find_all("div")
```

which is fine, but you then should walk over those scores:

```
for score in scores:
    scoreHi = score.find_all("div", {"class":"scoreHi"})
    Hi = scoreHi[0].text
    scoreMed = score.find_all("div", {"class":"scoreMed"})
    Med = scoreMed[0].text
    scoreLow = score.find_all("div", {"class":"scoreLow"})
    Low = scoreLow[0].text
```

Trying to iterate over the Doc (i.e. `soup`) using:

```
for scores in soup:
```

makes no sense.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how I miss that !

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, please consider *accepting* it by clicking the ✔ (checkmark) next to the answer. That is the way other people know your problem has been solved, without reading the comments. It also changes the appearance of the question and this answer in lists. If a better answer comes along, you can always change the accepted answer.